# Can Rational Team Concert and IntelliJ coexist?

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea, rtc

I am a long time intellij user.

The company where I work is likely to introduce Rational Team Concert to our department shortly. I went to the RTC demo and it looks like a reasonable product, built around Eclipse, but I would rather not give up using IntelliJ.

Does anyone have experience of using non-eclipse IDEs with RTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the answer is no.

Coexistence could cover many aspects; source code repository, Task lists, builds etc. But the first step would be integrating with source code repository and RTC uses something called Jazz.

There seems to be no available plugin nor plans for such.

Comment: Times have changed since this answer was provided. See https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/gsd/w3solutiondetails.do?solutionId=42148&lc=en&state=P

Comment: Yes, cm-logic.com has an RTC plugin for IntelliJ. However it is not free. When enquired, it costs around $400. Twice the cost of the IDE. :(

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be hard - you could configure IntelliJ to call the RTC scm commands, but this is not going to be that easy.  I have heard of a company planning to build an integration, but not seen this myself (they might have finished this already).  Company is called CM-Logic and is UK-based.

Answer (score 2):

Rational Team Concert's [integration page](https://jazz.net/extend/integrations/#tool=IntelliJ%20IDEA) says "Jazz Connect for IntelliJ IDEA enables developers using JetBrains to leverage the power of Rational Team Concert for source control, work item management, and collaboration services."

Also have a look at [this page](https://jazz.net/projects/rational-team-concert/integrations/) for other integrations of RTC.

Answer (score 2):

I use both of them together.  You can't use IDEA to checking or deliver code, but you can certainly edit code in IDEA and then use the RTC tools to checkin.

One warning: I'm on Ubuntu 64-bit, and everything is fine.  I have a co-worker using IDEA & RTC on Windows 7 and he has to close IDEA every time he wants to check-in because IDEA has file locks that RTC balks at.

I have no knowledge of the CM Logic's JazzConnect-IDEA product.  There doesn't seem to be any way to download a demo of it either.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Could you please explain what precautions you used to avoid messing up the Eclipse project when importing it in IntelliJ? I'm in your situation.

Comment: Well, that was 5 years ago, but I don't remember taking any precautions at all.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Just imported the project and told IntelliJ to keep its files in a separate directory. I'd also like to setup RTC in IDEA (there is a plugin) but it seems impossible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure RTC can use GIT these days.  Maybe you can convince your folks to use GIT so everybody is happy?

Comment: It's an outsourced project, so I cannot do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it could, it looks like IntelliJ offers an version control integration point as does the Jazz SCM component, but I am not familiar enough with IntelliJ to say for sure(looks like ClearCase is already on the list so they are adding support for vendors), I would think that without a full fledged integration where your Work Items are integrated into your development RTC starts to loose it's flair but may be not for your management :)

Answer (score 0):

Update on this: A new feature for Intellij is in the works, and planned or release this year. Here is the internal RFE. The links tab has a video recording of RTC integration with IDEA. 
https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=358932&tab=com.ibm.team.workitem.tab.links (Jazz ID authentication required)